# mediaelement-and-player.js how to listen ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a video tag in my html. The source has `application/x-mpegURL`,`rtmp/flv,application/x-mpegURL` tags. But some times in chrome it works and some times in microsoft edge it doesn't work. If I want to listen:

```
<video class="vi video-js" swf="./js/video-js.swf" controls="controls"   autoplay="autoplay"   preload="auto" width="250" height="190">
    <source src='xxxx' type="application/x-mpegURL" />
    <source src='xxxx' type="rtmp/flv" />
    <source src='xxxx' type="application/x-mpegURL" />
</video>
<script>
    $('video,audio').mediaelementplayer({
        pauseOtherPlayers: false,
        success: function (player, node) {
            player.pause()
            player.setMuted(true)
        }
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try below ... usually MP4 does work on most modern browsers. I am not sure what your .swf does. this has worked me on most browsers